# Align Group Box on a DockPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a group box on a DockPanel in xaml. I want it to re size when the window re-sizes but it does not. Please help

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ForceCursor="False">
 <GroupBox Header=" Select function" Height="183" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="16,16,12,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
 </GroupBox>
 <GroupBox Header=" Select function1" Height="183" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="16,25,12,0" Name="groupBox2" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
 </GroupBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Resize how? Vertically, horizontally or both?

Comment: Just horizontally. I want the group box to stay on the top vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" ForceCursor="False">
    <GroupBox Header=" Select function" Height="183" Margin="16,16,12,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    </GroupBox>
</DockPanel>
```

I changed the `LastChildFill` to `True` and because you said you want the `GroupBox` to be on Top I added `VerticalAlignment="Top"`.

Comment: That works. Thanks. I do have another question though. What if I want to add another group box under the previous? Actually the second group box does not come under the old one. I have edited the question.

Comment: In your updated code, add `DockPanel.Dock="Top"` to the two GroupBoxes. You don't need `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and the `Width="Auto"` and `Height="Auto"`.

I suggest you read up on how the DockPanel lays out its children.
This is a very basic online tutorial: [DockPanel layout](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/dockpanel/)